# iphone How to convert today date and time to GMTFormat(10 digits)

Tags: ios

I have locale date and time I am using the following code

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"current time:%@",currentTime);
```

Here i got localTime

Now i am converting local time to GMT Time
I am using the following code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss  MM dd yyyy "];
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentTime];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentTime];
```

Now my problem is i want to convert this GMT date into 10digit format like 1362468453

For that purpose i am using

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

How to get GMT Time in tendigits format

Answer (score 0):

Use `timeIntervalSince1970` function for your date to get `epoch time`.

```
NSLog(@"Epoch Time : %f", [dateFromString timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

Check this [NSDate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970)